# Openfire + Candychat 500 Internal error

Tags: apache, xmpp, openfire, basichttpbinding

Hi i am very new with this xmpp protocol and trying to build a simple web-based chat app using Openfire and candychat.

Currently i am running my webserver using XAMPP (C:\xampp). I already have openfire installed at C:\Openfire.

I already forked Candychat via github and put it inside my xampp/htdocs.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule http-bind/ http://localhost:7070/http-bind/ [P]
```

While my index.html (under the example folder of Candychat) looks like this (i omitted most of the codes):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Candy.init('http-bind/', {
            core: { debug: true },
            view: { resources: 'res/' }
        });

        Candy.Core.connect();
    });
</script>
```

When i try to access it via apache (via web browser) everything went normal, i get the proper login screen. However as i enter the username + password firebugs detects that there is 500 error ("NetworkError: 500 Server Error").

Looking back to my OpenFire admin page (specifically the event log) this is what i get:

```
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:875)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:441)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:936)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:801)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2013.04.18 14:03:46 org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpBindServlet - Error sending packet to client.
org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpConnectionClosedException: The http connection is no longer available to deliver content
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpConnection.deliverBody(HttpConnection.java:117)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession.addConnection(HttpSession.java:785)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession.createConnection(HttpSession.java:720)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSessionManager.forwardRequest(HttpSessionManager.java:316)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpBindServlet.handleSessionRequest(HttpBindServlet.java:254)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpBindServlet.parseDocument(HttpBindServlet.java:176)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpBindServlet.doPost(HttpBindServlet.java:145)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:547)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:941)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:409)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:875)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:441)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:936)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:801)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:586)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:44)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:598)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:533)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am not really sure what happen here, can anyone help me with this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, i already fixed the problem. Somewhat my antivirus block the port 7070. What i did is restart Openfire, and disable my AV or i suppose you could unblock that specific port.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer. You should also click the "accept" checkmark, as it describes the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ben Companjen

Thanks for the tips,

I already fixed this problem. It seemed to be my Anti Virus that causing this problem. What i did is

1. Make sure the HTTP Bind configuration is pointing to the right port
2. Make sure my AV is not interfering with said port.
3. Restart OpenFire everytime changes is made through the admin panel.

Cheers